# How to get the SMTP header of an email with an outlook add in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, smtp, outlook-addin

I'd like to get the SMTP header of the selected email in outlook.

I looked all over the API, but I can't find how to do this using the Office API : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx

I also tried looking what's available in the Message object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161175.aspx) :

`Office.context.mailbox.item.?`

I'm wondering if I should not use an Exchange Web Services (EWS) to do this ?

I'm asking because I have no idea if it is doable. I just tried to show you the process I've been through so far.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean exactly by SMTP header? Do you mean MIME headers?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. =)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a reference to the [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx) object, do the following:

```
var headers = item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E");
```

Where `item` is an instance of the MailItem class.

This will read the [PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815628.aspx) property.

Comment: So this is using C# in an EWS, right ? Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library ?

Comment: This is in C# using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library. Not EWS. I am assuming your are writing an outlook addin, why would you need EWS in an outlook addin?

Comment: I don't know why I'd need an EWS, I never developed one. I'm trying to understand the context your talking about. I'm developing an add-in outlook, but I think there is a confusion on the internet about this key words "add-in Outlook", because I'm doing it using JS and HTML. It's the kind of add-in that you open inside Outlook via an `<iframe>`. I'm never using C# here, though I did figure I might need to use it to do what I want here. Here is a demo video for add-in Outlook the way I do it : https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-694 Are we talking of the same thing ?

Comment: It seems we are doing different things. I really don't know about the kind of addins you are trying to make. I am not sure if there is a way in your case to read a MAPI property.

Comment: That's why I thought I could write a C# program to do this using the API you are talking about and call it using an EWS...

Comment: If you use C# to write a [VSTO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) add-in, then you can use the code I provided which does not require you to use EWS.